# WinRT GridView Stacking

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In the default application there is a gridview that displays groups of data stacked on top of each other (2 boxes high for each group).

When I implement my grid view it doesn't stack.  It is just 1 horizontal list.
I've compared my GridView to the default application and it appears to be VERY SIMILAR.  Is there a command I'm missing or do I have to setup my data differently?

Any help is appreciated.

**My GridView:**

```xaml
<GridView
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="vehicleGridView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="vehicles"
    TabIndex="1"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="83,0,-83,-4"
    Padding="116,0,116,46"
    ItemsSource="{Binding vehicles}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
    SelectionMode="None"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick ="vehicleClick">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                        <Button
                            AutomationProperties.Name="VehicleMake"
                            Content="{Binding VehicleMake}"
                            Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
</GridView>
```

**Default Example:**

```xaml
   <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                            <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Click="Header_Click"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
```

Comment: what you mean by stacking, can you show a screenshot?

Comment: I'll have to do that tonight.  It basically looks like it wraps in the grid.  So you have your top row of buttons and then you have your bottom row when it gets to a certain width.  I'll add a screenshot tonight.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I am having really hard time picturing it, having a concept wireframe or screenshot will help understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use WrapGrid in your ItemsPanelTemplate. Try this.

```xaml
<ItemsPanelTemplate><WrapGrid /></ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: you are correct.  I found that last night and was going to update this post today.  Thank you!